# Semantic-ui-react - Table Cell Colspan

Tags: semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

How to merge few cells in `semantic-ui-react` as we normally do using colspan in html table?

https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/table#types-pagination

I tried different options - nothing seems to help!!

[image]

Comment: `<Table.Cell colSpan="3">` is this what are you after? Note that the value of colSpan is in quotation marks "3"

Comment: @euvs Thanks. please add this as an answer!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The value of the `colSpan` property needs to be either in quotation marks ("3") or in curly braces ({3}). Otherwise it will be an incorrect React JSX syntax.

`<Table.Cell colSpan="3">`

or

`<Table.Cell colSpan={3}>`